# What is wrong with my .py code and how do I get this to run in a linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux

```
def WCTemp(temp,velocity):
    '''
    >>> WCTemp(32,10)
    23.44
    >>> WCTemp(80,30)
    82.07
    '''
    #place code here
    v = velocity**0.16
    r = 35.74 + 0.6125 * temp - 35.75 * v + 0.4275 * temp * v
    a = "%.2f" % r
    return (a)
```

I want to be able to open terminal, go to the directory this test.py file is in, type "python -i test.py", then be able to type "WCTemp(32,10)", and get the answer of 23.44.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hw1.py", line 15, in <module>
print ("%.2f" % WCTemp(temp,velocity))
NameError: name 'temp' is not defined
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please tell us what your code is suppose to do and what is the issue that you are having? We need to know more than "what is wrong with my .py code" :)

Comment: Step 1. Save the file as `test.py` in `~` (Home) folder. Step 2. Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` Step 3. Type `python test.py` and press `enter` ... *Voila* , your program executes

Comment: Tell me if I'm right: as an end result, you want to be able to open your terminal as normal and type `WCTemp(any, numbers)` and get the result printed to stdout?

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+T` can do anything, e.g. for me it does nothing...

Comment: your code does output what you want

Comment: Your edit just totally changed your question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's because I have to return the answer 23.44 instead of printing it.

Comment: @JaredLail, if you do what you are saying it will work. Have you saved it in  file test.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the doctests:

```
def WCTemp(temp,velocity):
    '''
    >>> WCTemp(32,10)
    '23.44'
    >>> WCTemp(80,30)
    '82.07'
    '''
    #place code here
    v = velocity**0.16
    r = 35.74 + 0.6125 * temp - 35.75 * v + 0.4275 * temp * v
    a = "%.2f" % r
    return (a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

pass the -v flag to see the output:

```
~$ python   test.py  -v
Trying:
    WCTemp(32,10)
Expecting:
    '23.44'
ok
Trying:
    WCTemp(80,30)
Expecting:
    '82.07'
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   2 tests in __main__.WCTemp
2 tests in 2 items.
2 passed and 0 failed.
```

If you have saved it in a file as you have in your question python -i `test.py`  will work exactly how you want:

test.py:

```
def WCTemp(temp,velocity):
    '''
    >>> WCTemp(32,10)
    23.44
    >>> WCTemp(80,30)
    82.07
    '''
    #place code here
    v = velocity**0.16
    r = 35.74 + 0.6125 * temp - 35.75 * v + 0.4275 * temp * v
    a = "%.2f" % r
    return (a)

~$ python -i v.py
>>> WCTemp(32,10)
'23.44'
```

Comment: I ran the doctests and it said that it failed. it expected 23.44 and got '23.44' instead, how do I get rid of the quotes?

Comment: one is a float and the other is a string , I edited the answer

Comment: Is there a way I can keep it as a float?

Comment: don't cast it to a string using `a = "%.2f" % r` or return `float(a)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to run this code from the command-line (i.e >>> python3 file.py), you'll need to save it as a module (file.py), and refactor it to the following:

```
def WCTemp(temp,velocity):
    '''
    >>> WCTemp(32,10)
    23.44
    >>> WCTemp(80,30)
    82.07
    '''
    #place code here
    v = velocity**0.16
    return 35.74 + 0.6125 * temp - 35.75 * v + 0.4275 * temp * v

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("%.2f" % WCTemp(32, 10))
```

But first, you'll need to pass values for your `temp` and `velocity` arguments in your print statement. Otherwise, your function has nothing to calculate!

Comment: Yeah, that's because you need to pass values for arguments in your print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `print` line to:

```
print ("%.2f" % WCTemp(32,10))
```

and run your program with: `python file.py`

where `file.py` is the name of file containing the code.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are trying to do this.

```
def WCTemp(temp,velocity):
    v = velocity**0.16
    r = 35.74 + 0.6125 * temp - 35.75 * v + 0.4275 * temp * v
    print ("%.2f" % r)


WCTemp(32,10)
```